# Updating a wxPython progress bar after calling app.MainLoop()

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I have a python script that performs a calculation, and I have created a class for a pop-up wxPython progress bar. Currently I have:

```
app=wx.App()
progress = ProgressBar()
app.MainLoop()

for i in xrange(len(toBeAnalysed)):
    analyse(toBeAnalysed[i])
    progress.update(i/len(toBeAnalysed)*100)
```

Now, this example doesn't work for obvious reasons. Is there any way I can run the app.MainLoop() in a different thread but still communicate the progress (and .update() it) as the calculations are completed?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

You should run your logic in a background thread and use `wx.CallAfter` to periodically update the GUI. `CallAfter` will invoke the provided function on the GUI thread, so it is safe to make GUI calls.

```
import wx
import threading
import time

def do_stuff(dialog): # put your logic here
    for i in range(101):
        wx.CallAfter(dialog.Update, i)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    wx.CallAfter(dialog.Destroy)

def start(func, *args): # helper method to run a function in another thread
    thread = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args)
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()

def main():
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    dialog = wx.ProgressDialog('Doing Stuff', 'Please wait...')
    start(do_stuff, dialog)
    dialog.ShowModal()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```